# Replicate Stata's marginal effects from multinomial logit regression in R

Tags: r, replication, multinomial, nnet, marginal-effects

I am trying to replicate Stata's marginal effects from multinomial logit models in R but with no success. For the multinomial logit model, I used the `multinom()` function from the `nnet` package and for the marginal effects I used the `margins` package but the `marginal_effects` function seems to only display effects of a single variable. What if I want to have the marginal effects of the variable conditioned on another variable? Here is the output from Stata:

```
. margins, dydx(male) at(site=(1 2 3)) #male conditioned on site

Average marginal effects                        Number of obs     =        615
Model VCE    : OIM

dy/dx w.r.t. : 1.male
1._predict   : Pr(insure==Indemnity), predict(pr outcome(1))
2._predict   : Pr(insure==Prepaid), predict(pr outcome(2))
3._predict   : Pr(insure==Uninsure), predict(pr outcome(3))

1._at        : site            =           1

2._at        : site            =           2

3._at        : site            =           3

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
1.male       |
_predict#_at |
        1 1  |  -.1492951   .0728108    -2.05   0.040    -.2920016   -.0065885
        1 2  |   -.159346   .0723512    -2.20   0.028    -.3011517   -.0175403
        1 3  |   -.055138   .0875712    -0.63   0.529    -.2267745    .1164984
        2 1  |   .0763095   .0765406     1.00   0.319    -.0737074    .2263264
        2 2  |   .1747759   .0730055     2.39   0.017     .0316877    .3178641
        2 3  |   .0861997   .0843816     1.02   0.307    -.0791852    .2515846
        3 1  |   .0729855   .0516839     1.41   0.158    -.0283131    .1742842
        3 2  |  -.0154299   .0104982    -1.47   0.142     -.036006    .0051462
        3 3  |  -.0310617   .0495625    -0.63   0.531    -.1282025    .0660791
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
```

My attempt to calculate the marginal effects of male using the `marginal_effects` function:

```
library(nnet)
sysdsn1$insure <- as.factor(sysdsn1$insure)
sysdsn1$male <- as.factor(sysdsn1$male)
sysdsn1$site <- as.factor(sysdsn1$site)
sysdsn1$nonwhite <- as.factor(sysdsn1$nonwhite)
sysdsn1$insure <- relevel(sysdsn1$insure, ref = "3") #set the reference level
mn0 <- multinom(insure ~ age + male*site + nonwhite, data = sysdsn1) #multinomial logit model
head(marginal_effects(mn0, variables = "male")) #this only calculate marginal effects of male, how to condition on site?
   dydx_male1
1 -0.01310874
2 -0.01744213
3  0.07911846
4 -0.03386199
5 -0.01728126
6 -0.01638176
```

**Data**

Data can be downloaded from http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/sysdsn1.dta and imported into R

Comment: Have you looked at the [`margins`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html) package? Not sure if it works with `nnet` though.

Comment: It does seem to support nnet objects: https://rdrr.io/github/leeper/margins/man/margins.html